# Adding variables to prestashop confirmation page

Tags: php, variables, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to add an analytics code to the confirmation page of `prestashop` 1.6.0.11. 
The analytics code is described in the following link
[Click](https://developer.skroutz.gr/analytics/)

I understand (?) that in order to provide the variables needed, I need to edit the `controllers/front/OrderConfirmationController.php` file and the `theme/order-confirmation.tpl` template.

so far I have managed to add the `order id` and the value of the order by adding the following code to the `OrderConfirmationController.php` file under

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
'shipping_cost_with_tax' => $order->total_shipping_tax_incl,
'reference_order' => $this->reference))
```

I need to add shipping cost and tax paid 
And I also need add 
`order_id`, Required, `product_id`,`product name`, `product price`, and `quantity` for each product.

Adding those variables to the template should be easy from that point. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. Just override your controller (http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors#Overridingdefaultbehaviors-Overridingacontroller).

Use $order->getProducts() to get order details.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for answering. Seems to work although I cannot get the order id. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging around I found this to work for me

```
$order->reference
$product.product_id
$product.product_name
displayPrice price=$product.unit_price_tax_incl
$product.product_quantity
```

Thanks anyway